# webdriver.io: Find elements within an iframe

Tags: iframe, webdriver

I am trying to access elements that are within an iframe on a webpage.

The goal is to switch to this iframe context and then click on elements within this iframe. These elements are not visible outside of the iframe, but when I switch to this iframe I am still unable to see the elements.

Using developer tools in the browser I am able to find each of the elements that I'm looking for in the iframe. I have tried referencing these elements by xpath both before switching to the iframe and after with no luck. There is only 1 iframe on this page.

While debugging I have tried to find any elements within the iframe by:

```
webDriver.$(`iFrame`).$(`*`).getText()
webDriver.$(`iFrame`).$(`*`).isExisting()
```

Or after switching to the iframe:

```
webDriver.$(`*`).getText()
webDriver.$(`*`).isExisting()
```

In both instances they return nothing: ``

I have tried updating the frameworks to see if that was an issue, and have tried Chrome and Firefox with the same result.

Has anyone else come across a similar issue with iframes before?

Comment: You have not provided any details of the website, or view of the elements to be able to help. So I have provided my training example that I did with my team in an answer below, to see if that helps you

Answer (score 0):

On webdriver.io the command for switching context to the iframe is
browser.switchToframe('locatorForYourIFrame')

https://webdriver.io/docs/api/webdriver#switchtoframe

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example (language: java - as none specified in question, however principle can be retro fitted for other selenium flavours) of what I demonstrated to my team using a public website. The website pops up a consent form (to allow cookies, date etc.) via a iframe on the the website. In the image below, xpath content from the webpage DOM has a highlight block to identify the following:

1. iframe - green box
2. button (WebElement) that we want to click within the iframe - red box

[image: stackOverflow_question_69943152]

Below is the code using selenium java with chromedriver/browser, this can be retro fitted for other selenium flavours / browsers

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

//Navigate to website
driver.get("https://www.empireonline.com");

//Find number of iframes on the page
int iframeCount = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size();
System.out.println("Number of Frames on a Page: "+iframeCount);

//Locate the iframe by id
WebElement iframe1=driver.findElement(By.id("sp_message_iframe_452327"));

//Switch to the iframe
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe1);

//Locate the element within the iframe and click(in this case the 'Accept All' button)
WebElement iframe1Button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@title,'Accept All')]"));
iframe1Button.click();

//Switch back to the main webpage
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

You can locate the iframe with whatever options are available, as in the picture, the iframe has a title tag, so it can also be located via xpath, see below:

```
//Locate the iframe by xpath using the title tag
WebElement iframe1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@title,'SP Consent Message')]"));
```