# Pop up Modal Power Apps

Tags: selenium, powerapps

[This image is borrowed from the internet since I can't post the actual picture due to confidentiality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiebS.png)

How to handle pop up modal like this in Power Apps thru Selenium Java? I can locate the element but when I try to interact with it when running the script, it cannot locate the element.

Comment: Welcome - I posted an answer previously, see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69974832/11543023

Comment: I've already switched to iframe but it is still not being handled. It does not recognize the dialog

Comment: Can you find a public internet example that is similar to your issue, provide the page / dom etc. so we have a demonstration of what you are experiencing, so we can help